# Where can I find how this mongodb connect function is implemented?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query, database-connection

I ctrl+clicked on the MongoClient.connect method so I can check how this is implemented,
the driver (npm i mongodb) is apparently written in TS,

all of that is fine, however all I could find is several versions of the method (overloaded function), and I still can't find where it is implemented!
please help me understand what am I missing!

the line below is where I reached

```
static connect(uri: string, options: MongoClientOptions, callback: MongoCallback<MongoClient>): void;
```

Comment: Maybe tell us what you mean by "I ctrl+clicked on the MongoClient.connect method ..."

Comment: ctrl+clicking in VScode takes you to where a variable, function, or class etc. is declared and also shows where it is used, generally speaking finds you the instances of what you clicked

Comment: I don't think the driver is written in TS. I think it's pure JS. See if you can find the function in question in https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/ each method there has a link to the actual source.

Answer (score 0):

thank you @kevinadi
I followed the link, and then clicked the reference to the source, which took me to:
https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/lib_mongo_client.js.html

this made the implementation clear